# Can not get DOM element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am trying to get DOM element from jQuery selector array.

```
var n = $(this).index();
$title = $(".title:not(.small)")[n];
```

Yet it only returns text and not DOM element as I want it to.
I want to get DOM element so i can get the elements position on the page and scroll to it.

$(this) = list element
.title = there are few  elements on the page with class="title" and "title small".

Thank you

PS: I could not find anything similar on stackoverflow or anywhere on google. It could be that I don't know how to correctly google this "error".

Comment: It is not clear from what you provided that you would get text. Please provide a working (runnable) snippet that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `[n]` notation is the same as [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/): it gets the underlying DOM element.

To get a jQuery selection, use [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$title = $(".title:not(.small)").eq(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(".title:not(.small)")[n]` will return DOM element not jQuery object. You can use [**`eq()`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method like following.

```
var n = $(this).index(),
    $title = $(".title:not(.small)").eq(n);
```